# cancan ability - read/manage only one specific instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Sorry - in a brain fog!

We have a rails app using cancan. Right now we have a menu that does this kind of thing:

```
<%= link_to "Devices", devices_path if can? :read, Device %>
```

But, this is great if the person can read ALL devices... but fails if the person can only read one specific device. We are using a role object.

How do we act on the fact that the user can :read ONE Device?

Answer (score 1):

assume in your controller:

```
@device = Device.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
```

and in your VIEW:

```
<%= link_to "Devices", devices_path if can? :read, @device %>
```

and in cancan's ability file:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :read, Device, :user_id => user.id
  end
end
```

more details please refer to https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities